# Why does the computer having data from Dr. Mann's planet react in this way?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

In the movie [Interstellar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_%28film%29) on Dr. Mann's planet when Rommily tries to check the data from the computer or robot he says "This data makes no sense" and then suddenly it blows up killing Rommily. Now how could Dr. Mann program the computer such that it blows up when someone sees it. Is it really possible for an astronaut to do computer programming so cleverly that it turns into a bomb when opened? Or did he plant a physical bomb into the computer that blew up? I Am confused, please help me.